# Inequality with lateral limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be one interval and $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $x_0\in I$ is a point such that the right hand side limit of $f$ exist at that point, that is, the limit

$$L = \lim_{x\to x_0^+} f(x),$$

exists. I want to show that there's $\delta >0$ such that $(x_0,x_0+\delta)\subset I$ and

$$f(x)\leq\dfrac{3}{2}L,$$

for all $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta)$.

Now, from the existence of $L$ what we know is that given $\epsilon > 0$ there's $\delta > 0$ such that if $x\in (x_0,x_0+\delta)$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. I believe it is then a matter of picking the right $\epsilon$. Indeed we have that

$$-\epsilon < f(x)-L<\epsilon, \quad \forall x\in (x_0,x_0+\delta),$$

so that

$$f(x) <\epsilon+L,$$

then if $\epsilon = L/2$ we get the result. But this only works if $L>0$. It could happen that $L < 0$. In that case, how do we treat the case $L <0$?

Comment: That should be a hint that what you want to show is not true. Let $f(x)=x$ and $I =\left(-\frac{3}{2},-1\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. In fact, this *never* holds when $L<0$. Suppose $L<0$. Then for $\epsilon$ small enough  and some $\delta$ we have

$$\frac{3}{2}L < L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$$

for all $x \in (x_0, x_0 + \delta)$.